# How to open file automaticalty - PL/SQL(Oracle SQL Developer)

Tags: oracle, file, plsql, sqlplus, spool

I am writing using the spool command to a file and I would like when I finish writing and use the spool off command that the file opens automatically for the user.

How can I open the file automatically with PL/SQL?

Thank you!

Comment: With PL/SQL?  PL/SQL is a procedural language that runs entirely inside the database server. It has no ability to interact with the client's display or keyboard.  And 'spool' is a sqlplus command that has no relationship to the pl/sql language   Since you say 'open automatically for the user', I presume the user is using some tool to submit a sql script.  Just as sqlplus has a 'spool' command to write all the output to a file that is local to the sqlplus session, it also has the 'edit' command that will spawn the default OS editor (vi in linux, notepad in Windblows).

Comment: @EdStevens just to be more correct re "edit": not default OS editor, but specified in the variable `_EDITOR`, you can redefine it easily, for example: `DEFINE _EDITOR  ="/usr/bin/mcedit"`

Comment: Short answer is you can't. PL/SQL can't see your files and doesn't know that you are spooling. It runs in the database.

Answer (score 1):

SQL*Plus, SQL Developer and SQLCl have a special command `HOST` for such things:

- [SQL*Plus](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve026.htm#SQPUG047)
- [Oracle SQL Developer and SQLCl](https://docs.oracle.com/database/sql-developer-17.3/SQCQR/toc.htm#SQCQR-GUID-CD559E5B-FDC3-40DA-B699-E2EBFC4C5D9B)

So you can add a command `host` with `open` on Linux/Unix and `start` on Windows.
For example, I define a substitution variable `_START` in my `glogin` script:

- [on_login_nix.sql](https://github.com/xtender/xt_scripts/blob/master/inc/on_login_nix.sql): `DEFINE _START   ="open"`
- [on_login_win.sql](https://github.com/xtender/xt_scripts/blob/master/inc/on_login_win.sql): `DEFINE _START   ="start"`

and then use it as `host &_START &spoolfile`, for example in my script [`sqlid_exec_html.sql`](https://github.com/xtender/xt_scripts/blob/master/rtsm/sqlid_exec_html.sql) for RTSM reports:

```
spool &MON_FILE

SELECT
    DBMS_SQLTUNE.REPORT_SQL_MONITOR( 
       SQL_ID       => '&MON_SQLID',
       sql_exec_id  => '&MON_SQLEXEC',
       report_level => 'ALL',
       type         => 'ACTIVE') as report   
FROM dual
/
spool off
host &_START &MON_FILE
```

But sometimes (if shell/terminal supports your file extension), you can just type `host &spoolfilename`.